# Terrraform list of objects syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm using a module that references a central module used to build a Puppet server in terraform. There is one variable in the root module that allows additional tags to be used with the ASG however I can't seem to get the syntax right. This is the information in the core repository:

```
   variable "additional_asg_tags" {
  description = "A map of additional tags to add to the puppet server ASG."
  type        = list(object({ key = string, value = string, propagate_at_launch = bool }))
  default     = []
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of to call this but it always errors with messages like "incorrect list element type: string required." or "This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: list of object required."

I'm trying to call the above with something like;

```
variable "additional_asg_tags" {
  description = "A map of additional tags to add to ASG."
  type        = list(object({ key = string, value = string, propagate_at_launch = bool }))
  default     = { key = "Name", value = "Puppet-nonprod", propagate_at_launch = "true" 
 }
}
```

I've removed the square braces around this as that was causing errors also but I may need to add these back in.

Can someone help please in what is the correct way to reference a list of objects with these values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **correct** default value for your `additional_asg_tags` is a `list`:

```
variable "additional_asg_tags" {

  description = "A map of additional tags to add to ASG."
  
  type = list(object({
               key = string, 
               value = string, 
               propagate_at_launch = bool
            }))
            
  default = [{ 
        key = "Name", 
        value = "Puppet-nonprod", 
        propagate_at_launch = "true" 
   }]
}
```

You can **reference** individual elements as follows (some examples):

```
var.additional_asg_tags[0]["key"]

var.additional_asg_tags[0].value

# to get list 
var.additional_asg_tags[*].propagate_at_launch
```

Comment: thank you @Marcin. Unfortunately when I try that I get this error again; .terraform/pathToRemoteFile/variables.tf:329,1-44: incorrect list element type: string required. Could this potentially be an error in the root module?

Comment: @scrow I don't know what is your root module. Its not shown in the question, nor how it relates to your `additional_asg_tags`.