# How to loop through nested maps in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, api-gateway

I am creating hierarchical endpoints in AWS api gateway and want to loop through my local variable to create endpoints in api-gateway. My local variable looks like this:

```
{
  "api" = {
    "v1" = [
      {
        "method" = "GET"
        "name" = "route_1"
        "uri" = "https://test-api.example.com/api/v1/route_1"
      },
      {
        "method" = "GET"
        "name" = "route_2"
        "uri" = "https://test-api.example.com/api/v1/route_2"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to have a nice tree like this in api-gateway.

[image]

I am new to terraform. Is there a simple way to acheive this? Here's my example Terraform code.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_test" {
  name = "qa-api"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = [ "REGIONAL" ]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api" {
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_test.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "api"
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_test.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "MyDemoMethod" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_test.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.api.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "MyDemoIntegration" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_test.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.api.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method
  type                 = "HTTP"
}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each?

Comment: Yes I have checked it, but this is a complex data structure and using only `for_each` will not be sufficient

Comment: You can use count over a list of objects, take a look to this answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/66222022/5220215

Comment: Your structure is not complex, that is just a list ... Can you explain why a `for_each` will not be sufficient?

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/QloudX/terraform-AWS-Lambda-REST-API
or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437059/terraform-dynamically-generate-rest-api-endpoints-in-aws-api-gateway-based-on-u